# register_shutdown_function not called in expected order

Tags: php

```
$packet = createPacket();
register_shutdown_function('sendEmail', $packet);

function createPacket()
{
    $packetId = 'test';
    register_shutdown_function('generatePacket');

    return $packetId;
}
```

problem is, sendEmail() is called before generatePacket(). Shouldn't generatePacket be called first because it's registered before?

Answer (score 2):

They are called in the same order as they were registered. Therefore `generatePacket()` will be called first, because it first registered inside the `createPacket()` function.

Test:

```
<?php
  function sendEmail($pk) {
    print("sendEmail($pk)\r\n");
  }

  function generatePacket() {
    print("generatePacket()\r\n");
  }

  $packet = createPacket();
  register_shutdown_function('sendEmail', $packet);

  function createPacket()
  {
      $packetId = 'test';
      register_shutdown_function('generatePacket');

      return $packetId;
  }
/* output:
generatePacket()
sendEmail(test)
*/
```

result is the same on all php versions: https://3v4l.org/UapPk